# getting data from rows after executing query

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

I am very new to DB application development, though I have a fair amount of experience in VB.NET and C++ (self-taught, somewhat intermediate). I have a query in a table adapter with two parameters (user input) that always returns only one row from a table, based on those two parameters. Let's say row X with A, B and C columns. Filters are set on A and B in my query, but it selects all fields.
Now, I want to show the value of C in one of my main Form objects (let's say a Label in this example), but I cannot seem to be able to extract it. I know it probably is very easy, but I am a bit lost in DB code jungle..

[EDIT]

My apologies, the code bit (example).

Query:

SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
WHERE (Column1 = @Parameter1) AND (Column2 = @Parameter2)

In my VB project:

Dim temp
temp=Me.Table1TableAdapter.queryName(Me.MyProjectDBDataSet.Table1,userinput1, userinput2)

Up to this point everything works perfectly, but this is also where I get stuck. How do I, let's say, assign the value of Column3 (after running the query the result will always be only one row from Table1) to Label.Text for instance?

I hope this makes it a bit clearer..

Comment: imagine how lost *we* are without any code at all; see [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase
Dim cmd As DbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query) 'Query is a string containing your SQL command'
Dim sqlDataReader As IDataReader = db.ExecuteReader(cmd)
Dim myObj As New MyObject    
If sqlDataReader IsNot Nothing Then
    'Loop through the rows of the DataReader'
    Do While sqlDataReader.Read()
        'Do something here with the value in Column3'
        myObj.myIntegerProperty= CInt(IIf(IsDBNull(.Item("Column3")), 0, .Item("Column3")))
    Loop
End If
```